# auto filling a cell with background colour

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wondering how to incorporate this functionality into an existing formula that reads:

```
=IF(M4491<4,"-1",IF(M4491=4,"0",IF(M4491=5,"1",IF(M4491=6,"2",IF(M4491>6,"3"))))
)
```

If for example the number or result in `M4491` is `5` then the answer in the target cell will be `1`. How do I automatically assign a background colour of RED to this target cell based on the answer of `1` or greater.

If the result in `M4491` is `4`, then the target cell result will be `0` and I want this cell to be BLUE background colour.

If the result in `M4491` is `3`, then the target cell result will be -1 and I want this cell to be GREEN background colour.

Answer (score 1):

Excel allows a 3-color scale format style, which is the maximum. However, we can get this done by applying more than one conditional formatting rule:

1. A 3-color scale that specifies the formatting rule for when a number is between 1 and 3 (both inclusive):

[image: 3-color scale]

2. Creating two rules that color only cells that contain specific values:

[image: Format only cells that contain]

After applying the third rule in a similar fashion, the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager box should look something like this:

[image: Result]

**Edit:**

You can simplify your formula by avoiding an extra nested `IF`:

```
=IF(M4491<4,-1,IF(M4491<5,0,IF(M4491<6,1,IF(M4491<7,2,3))))
```

Or if it's an option, you can skip it altogether, and use `VLOOKUP`. Assign your slab to a range, say, `A1:B5`, like this:

```
╔═══╦═══╦════╗
║   ║ A ║ B  ║
╠═══╬═══╬════╣
║ 1 ║ 0 ║ -1 ║
║ 2 ║ 4 ║  0 ║
║ 3 ║ 5 ║  1 ║
║ 4 ║ 6 ║  2 ║
║ 5 ║ 7 ║  3 ║
╚═══╩═══╩════╝
```

You can then use `VLOOKUP` to fetch the values:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$1:$B$5,2,1)
```